# Bind Broadcast function return 500 without any error meesage when binding "Stream now" broadcast ID

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

[image: Youtube Live v3 error response: 500]

I tried use YouTube livestream API to stream from my camera to Stream Now feature. I was able to retrieve the ID of "Stream Now" broadcast ID via the list/ API of broadcast: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/list

However when I tried to bind this broadcast ID using bind API/, either I was using streamID or not using streamID, I still receive 500 response without any detail from YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

500 is an internal server error.  Without an error message or stack trace, it will be difficult to tell what went wrong.

If you're using the "Stream Now" feature, it's possible that your `liveEvent` and your `liveBroadcast` objects have already been bound together.  If that is the case, you could hit the [`liveBroadcasts/bind`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/bind) endpoint with an empty `streamId` parameter to remove any existing bindings between the broadcast and a video stream.  Then you could call `/bind` again with a newly created stream to restore the video content.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I already tried to bind the "Stream now" broadcast ID with empty streamId (since it's optional) and the response was still 500. Actually to have 5xx response code on client side, I believe there should be something to do from youtube api.